# How do you repair or replace an ice maker in a Samsung RF23HCEDBBC Refrigerator?

Tags: repair, kitchens, appliances, refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a [Samsung RF23HCEDBBC](https://www.samsung.com/us/home-appliances/refrigerators/french-door/36-wide-23-cu-ft-capacity-french-door-refrigerator-black-rf23hcedbbc-aa/) that I bought a little over a year ago. All of the sudden, it stopped making ice in the ice maker.

What is bizarre is that if I click the ice maker "reset" and wait a few minutes, ice will release every time into the bucket (I can do this every few hours to fill up the bucket if I need ice).

The only advice on this model I could find is that the ice maker would freeze up. I didn't see any ice build up anywhere, but I removed everything from the refrigerator and defrosted the entire thing. It made ice perfectly for a few days without any problems, and then it stopped making ice again (again, hitting the reset will dump ice into the bucket).

I thought perhaps it was a water temperature issue, so played with the temperature of the refrigerator and the freezer, but that didn't seem to change anything.

I'm starting to think this is a sensor issue somewhere, but it's almost impossible to reach inside of it or see what is going on. Is there any way to repair or replace the ice maker?

Comment: is the freezer getting a lot of frost? You could have a door seal issue

Comment: @noybman There was a lot of frost in the freezer before defrosting. Since defrosting 2 weeks ago, there isn't any frost in the freezer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure the water feed tube is the new style that is open so it doesn't freeze but since it does drop that is likely not the issue.

Do you still get water from the water dispenser? If so likely not the solenoid. It could be the power harness, it is rare but sometimes they stop functioning.

Have you tried checking voltage when it isn't working? There should be a youtube somewhere showing you how to check that. In fact have you looked on youtube there are an amazing number of solutions to be found there, never overlook that.

One thing the manufacturers say is to not use third party filters. But honestly I have used them and the expensive manufacturer filters, and there is no difference in whether my ice maker works or not. It's all about the money. But you could buy one and give it a try.

The other thing you might try is lower the temp in your freezer, wait 24 hours for the temp to adjust, and they see if that helps. I do know the change of seasons effects all that. If the water comes in too hot or cold from normal, seems to cause issues. But there is really no way to control the weather and it should adjust on its own.

Good luck, ice makers are a huge problem for everyone.

Comment: Wow... this starts as a rant, continues as a hard to read, unformatted wall of text, then ends as a rant. Also, "Ther should be a youtube somewhere" isn't really up to the [standards we expect in a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please feel free to [edit] this to remove the rants, add formatting and some direct links (with description of what's happening for when the video disappears) and it might be a good answer.